# ASP.NET creating my own type to use in a domain object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am busy building my Domain for a new application and I came across the situation where I need to create my own type.

I want to create a type called Frequency.

It needs to be a decimal with 3 decimal places.

Some examples:

```
135.000
135.100
135.001 
etc
```

It always needs to have 3 decimal places.

I also want to put some specific bounds and validation on the object that is why I thought it would be best to create a custom type.

So my question is:

1. How do I go about doing this?
2. How do I get a decimal to always have 3 decimal places and to not go
   135.1 when it should be 135.000

Attempt:

```
public class Frequency
{
    private decimal frequency;

    public void setFrequency(Frequency tmp)
    {
        this.frequency = tmp;
    }

    public Frequency getFrequency()
    {
        return this.frequency;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Isn't this just a simple object with hardcoded ToString()-implementation that returns three decimals?

Comment: Yes, But what i dont know is how to override the default setters and getters so that I can use my object in my code like so: `Frequency temp = 152.120` I will post my attempt;

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `implicit` and `operator` keywords to achieve this:

```
public class Frequency
{
    private double freq;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return freq; }
        private set { freq = value; }
    }

    private Frequency(double value)
    {
        this.freq = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Frequency(double value)
    {
        return new Frequency(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator double(Frequency freq)
    {
        return freq.Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return freq.ToString("0.000");
    }
}
```

This allows you to set the value (`Frequency data = 153`) and also access it for mathematical operations

```
Frequency data = 153;
double multi = data * 153;
```